# Tails manual upgrade persistence lost

Tags: tails, update

I did a manual upgrade per the instructions on the tails website and I lost my persistence folder. I don't see any persistence folder

I had my original tails on a 8gb drive and the intermediary was 16gb.

Why am I not seeing any persistence folder?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should know that once in a while this happens since there are many tails, maybe the persistence.conf file got broken. But there is a way out to fix the difficulties your facing.
Try this:

-Boot Tails and enable persistence.

-Use the Tails file manager to look into the directory where the persistence volume is mounted to see if your files are still present.

-Top left menu bar > Places > Computer > File System > live > persistence > TailsData_unlocked

-There should be a number of directories with your saved data contained in them:

```
 electrum,  
 gnupg,  
 Persistent
```

(others depending on your configuration)
      If those directories are present, you may be able to fix your problem by simply re-running the persistence configuration tool.

-Applications > Tails > configure persistent volume

-Enable the same options that you had before.

-Reboot.

Hopefully your persistence volume will now be mounted properly.

However to prevent this;
Always shutdown your Tails system normally. Do not pull the drive out of the machine to shut it down. That is only to be used in an emergency and could cause data loss.

As a safety measure, keep you backups current.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue, check out this dedicated documentation:

https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/index.en.html#index16h2

Good luck!

> Persistent folder disappears and data of the Persistent Storage is unavailable
>
> Sometimes, the *Persistent* folder is missing and all the data of the Persistent Storage is unavailable.
>
> Most likely this means that the `persistence.conf` file has disappeared. However, the files in the *Persistent* folder and all the other data in the Persistent Storage should still exist.
>
> If you encounter this problem:
>
> 1. Unlock the Persistent Storage in the Welcome Screen when starting Tails.
> 2. Choose **Applications** ▸ **Tails** ▸ **Configure persistent volume**.
> 3. If you are asked to enter a passphrase, enter the same passphrase that you use to unlock your Persistent Storage.
> 4. Turn on the features of the Persistent Storage that you had turned on previously.
> 5. Click **Save**, then restart Tails.
>
> Your Persistent folder and all the data of the Persistent Storage should be restored.
>
> If the above instructions do not fix the problem, you might need to fix the ownership of `TailsData_unlocked`.
>
> To fix the ownership of `TailsData_unlocked`, set an administration password and execute the following command in a terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo chown root:root /live/persistence/TailsData_unlocked`
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Had a similiar issue today after unexpected shutdown during boot (after persistent storage was already unlocked). Tried the `sudo chown` but it didn't work. Luckily I had a cloned version on another USB-Stick from where I could still access the files when inserted the original stick as a regular USB while running the clone. I than updated the original from the clone than > configure persistent storage > turned off/on personal storage > save. Folder showed up again.